# Meta-analysis of standard deviation using the `metafor` package in R: can we distinguish between the different types of variability?

Tags: r, meta-analysis

I am doing meta-analysis of standard deviations of parameter X (gastric pH). My collated studies are conducted on humans and each study report mean plus/minus SD of gastric pH in the studied population.

I already did the meta-analysis of the standard deviations and got a meta-SD estimate. I used the `metafor` package in R.

I assume that the meta-estimate of SD is a composite of between subject variability, within subject variability, between occasion variability in gastric pH as well as between study heterogeneity.

My question:

Is there a way to differentiate between these different types of variability? or at least differentiate between (between study heterogeneity in the meta-SD estimate versus other types of variability?)

Comment: Before I started worrying about partitioning the heterogeneity I would be concerned about whether the $y_i$ are normal. If they are standard deviations it seems unlikely (and how did you estimate their standard errors?).

Comment: @mdewey I assumed that the SDs are normally distributed and the sampling varience for SD was calculated as `sigma^2/(2*n)` where sigma is the true variance (in my case is SD) and n is the number of subjects.

Comment: If you are using a random-effects model, you are already differentiating between between-study variability (heterogeneity) and (within-study) sampling error. And since your outcome is the SD, that's between-subject variability. Not sure what else you are looking for.

Comment: @Wolfgang Thank you for your input. Yes, I am using random-effect model. My thought was that the meta-SD estimate incorporated the between study heterogeneity in it?

Comment: @Amer What do you mean by 'meta-SD estimate'? The estimated average SD based on the RE model? And what do you mean by 'incorporate between study heterogeneity'?

Comment: @Wolfgang yes, I mean the estimated average SD from the RE model. I mean by  'incorporated between study heterogeneity' that the extent of between study heterogeneity affected, and was accounted for, in the estimated value of the average SD from the RE model. I am a learner here and wanted to clear this from my mind.

Comment: Yes, heterogeneity is taken into consideration in the calculation of the average SD in the RE model.

Comment: @mdewey if the meta-SD us interpreted as between subject variability. Can the analysis of SDs say anything about the within subject variability?

Comment: The meta-analysis combines the primary studies so if they are giving you a measure of within person variability then yes, otherwise no.

Answer (score 2):

Since you say that you are a learner you might be interested in the distinction between fixed effects (FE) and random effects (RE) models. Although these are often treated as just variants of one another in fact they are distinct models. Let us imagine their proponents speak to us.

Doctor FE says: I believe that the studies I have collected all estimate the same underlying parameter and so I will weight each estimate by its precision in order that the more precise studies get more weight.

Doctor RE says: I believe that there is no single underlying parameter and that my job is to estimate the parameters of its distribution. Since I assume it to be normal I can estimate its mean and variance. I shall then use weights based on both the variation between the studies and the precision of the individual studies. In the extreme this will lead to equal weights when there is much heterogeneity.

Note though that the heterogeneity is not accounted for in the sense of *explained* by the model. As you notice @Wolfgang in his comment carefully said it was '... taken into consideration ...'. If you have suitable moderator variables you may go on to explore the heterogeneity further of course but that is another story.